# How to pass an object (csv file) to HttpClient.PostAsync as a JSON body?

Tags: .net, csv, post, postasync

I am doing the test automation of a post request that takes a csv file (form data in postman) and returns a list.
I want to add a csv file as an object in the body of the postasync request in my code. However, I would like to know how to add the path of csv file and how to let it point on the csv file. In postman, i just have to upload the csv file in the body of the post request without reading it.

```
string Folder = "\\Uploads\\630.csv";
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(Folder);
var streamContent = new StreamContent(fs);
var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);          

var ResponseList = HttpService.PostAsync<ListResponseModel>($"https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/sellers/1233/offers", fileContent, token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: What does your API controller method look like? Does it accept a model?

Comment: I don't have an api controller method. should I have one ?

Comment: I mean you must be calling an api method yeah? I'm guessing called `sellers` or `offers`. Does it accept a model?

Comment: I didn't get it. What do you mean by a model ? I am doing the automation of the api test. so I don't really care about sellers and offers. instead of doing the call from postman i do it automatically with my code i just prepare the body (it's file content in this case)

Comment: I mean, you're obviously calling an API endpoint yeah? It's a `POST` so you've obviously sending it something. What are you sending it? Is it an object?

Comment: i have to get the access token first, prepare the body next and do the call.
 var ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
            var ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            var token = KeycloakService.GetTokenAsync(ClientId, ClientSecret).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Comment: Ok I get your point. I am trying to send a csv file.

Comment: Can you change your API endpoint or is it third party?

Comment: i can change the API endpoint

Comment: The problem that I have is with content body and not with the endpoint